# Java Scanner hasNext not matching a semicolon

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this code:

```
    while(s.hasNext()){
        //if (s.hasNext(LOOP))  {  nodes.add(parseLoop(s));  }
        if (s.hasNext("turnL;")){ nodes.add(new TurnLNode()); s.next();}
        if (s.hasNext("turnR;")){ nodes.add(new TurnRNode()); s.next();}
        if (s.hasNext("takeFuel;")){ nodes.add(new TakeFuelNode()); s.next();}
        if (s.hasNext("wait;")){ nodes.add(new WaitNode()); s.next();}
        if (s.hasNext("move;")){ nodes.add(new MoveNode()); s.next();}
        else{
            fail("Invalid command", s);
        }
    }
```

I'm scanning in this:

```
turnL;
move;
turnR
move;
```

And it's failing to scan the ; on the first line. Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Btw, shouldn't it be `if () {...} else if () {...} else if () {...} else {...}`? Actually your `else` is only part of your last `if`.

Comment: How is the scanner initialized? Why aren't you using `hasNextLine()`/`nextLine()`?

Comment: Matt - that was only one example that can be scanned in. Others can have multiple things on one line.

To be more precise about my problem, the ; isn't being scanned by s.next()

Comment: what @pzaenger said could solve the issue, try with what he said

Comment: Tried that....still not scanning in the ;

Comment: Please also show how the scanner is initialized, so we can see what its source is and what configuration may be used.

Comment: This: s.useDelimiter("\\s+|(?=[{}(),;])|(?<=[{}(),;])");

Comment: What, in words, is the delimiter you want to use? The problem is likely in this delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `s.next()`, the scanner's pointer advances, but all other statements in your `while` body will still be executed.

Additionally, your `else` statement only relates to your last `if` statement. So when the last `if` statement is reached, which it always is, the code recognizes that the first line doesn't match 'move;' and executes the `else` statement, thus failing.

You could fix this by adding `continue;` at the end of all if statements. This will make the while loop advance to its next iteration without executing the other if statements. Much better coding style would be to replace all but the first `if` statements with `else if`.

Comment: Just realized I missed part out of my question...it's not scanning in the ; on the first line of text

Comment: Try to explicitly set the scanner to only use newline as delimiter before the while loop starts: `s.useDelimiter("\\n")`. Alternatively, use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` (and `hasNextLine()` instead of `hasNext()`).

Comment: Still not working....just tried this:

System.out.println(s.hasNext("turnL"));

And it printed false

Comment: This means that `turnL` may be in there, but is not the next up token. Perhaps your file contains a new line first, or you placed this printline at the wrong place. Try simply printing `next()` on the start of each while iteration, or use `s.hasNextLine()` as condition and print `nextLine()`.

Comment: Some of the stuff I have to scan has multiple statements on a single line, so s.nextLine() isn't an option

Answer (score 0):

Using s.next() returns turnL, then the semicolon, then move, then the next semicolon etc etc. A quick workaround is to use a regex pattern for the turnL command, then in your parser use another pattern for the semicolon, and check if the semicolon follows the first pattern.

This is because looking at the delimiter you were given, and reading the commented code above in the assignment, it says 
// the only time tokens can be next to each other is 
// when one of them is one of (){},; so, it is separating the semi colon from everything else, meaning you'll need to add the semicolon as a separate check